# Expanding ext4 and shrinking NTFS partitions on the local drive

Tags: ext4

I have my machine dual booted with Linux Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr LTS and Windows 7 Ultimate both 64 bit. I want to shrink the E:/ i.e. /dev/sda5/ by around 10GB and expand the Ubuntu partition by those 10GB. The Ubuntu partition is /dev/sda7/. Both are in the same extended partition. I do want to do this without losing any data in any of partitions. I have a total of 7 partitions(4NTFS 1 EXT4 1SWAP) however there is no /dev/sda4 and the list extends to /dev/sda8. I can prefer repartitioning using either OS or even an external disk/USB. Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: If you have data that you cannot lose, you should already have good backups. And any partition change has risks. A power failure in the middle of change will totally corrupt system. Use Windows to shrink NTFS & run chkdsk after shrink. Then use gparted to move partitions and expand. Make sure you leave about 30% unallocated inside the NTFS partition or it gets slow.

Comment: U mean that I need to have at least 30% free space in the NTFS partition. Also since I am using a laptop I don't need to worry about power failure. Also would I be able to expand the partition from which I am booted up.

Comment: Windows tools seem to work from its install, but changes may not take place until you reboot. Yes you need lots of free space inside NTFS for it to work well. Why many complain after a period of time on Windows being slow. And many posts with users on laptops where battery ran out as task can take a while. Drives do fail, users drop laptops, many issues bappen and good backups are only way to recover in many cases.

Comment: Anyways Can I expand the partition from which I am booted up in Ubuntu?

Comment: You always use live installer, or if multiple drives can only use gparted on other drive. You cannot have any mounted partitions. You may have to swapoff or umount swap, as live installer will use a swap partition on your drive if found.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit further I have little knowledge about Linux file tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use Gparted

1. First of all unmount the required partitions.
2. Next using choose the required NTFS and right click and choose Resize/Move.
3. Shrink the partition as per your needs.
4. Repeat the steps with the ext4 partition.

Comment: can that be done on an external drive? https://askubuntu.com/q/1086716/47206